# What is a reason of error 'Out of memory'?

Tags: r, matrix, out-of-memory, igraph

I have a matrix B.

```
dim(B)
> 3025 3025
```

When I try to use this matrix in order to create graph object I recieved error:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph.adjacency(B, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)

# Error in .Call("R_igraph_weighted_adjacency", adjmatrix, 
# as.numeric(mode),  : 
# At vector.pmt:439 : cannot reserve space for vector, Out of memory
```

What is a reason of the error? Is this a limitation of R or my PC?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows Vista (build 6001) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] igraph_1.0.1
```

**Update** (after @Gabor comment). 
I tried to reproduce the error. I used:

```
B <- matrix(runif(3025*3025, 0, 10), nc = 3025) 
#Error: cannot allocate vector of size 69.8 Mb
g <- graph.adjacency(B, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)
object.size(B)
#73423056 bytes
object.size(g)
#395900 bytes
```

But the error is differ. The error was before call function from library(igraph). Then I wrote

```
B<-c()
>B
NULL
B <- matrix(runif(3025*3025, 0, 10), nc = 3025) 
g <- graph.adjacency(B, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)
Error in .Call("R_igraph_weighted_adjacency", adjmatrix, as.numeric(mode),  : 
  At vector.pmt:439 : cannot reserve space for vector, Out of memory
dim(B)
#[1] 3025 3025
object.size(B)
#73205112 bytes
object.size(g)
#395900 bytes
```

Comment: Windows Vista issue? 32-bit issue? `B <- matrix(sample(0:1, 9150625, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.9,0.1)), nc=3025); graph.adjacency(B, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)` works in a second on 64-bit Linux. What's inside `B`?

Comment: On my machine, I'm watching it go. It's using 43gb of RAM to compute. Then 60gb. I think it's made for smaller datasets.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Could you kindly share your snippet? I can't see such peak with the one I posted on comment.

Comment: I literally just ran `graph.adjecency` on `matrix(sample(0:100,3025*3025,replace = TRUE),ncol = 3025,nrow = 3025)`. Then I watch my system monitor go nuts.

Comment: 64bit-bit Nix, 64gb ram, equal swap. I shut it down once it started eating into my swap.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen  I see. `graph.adjacency(B)` effectively produces a peak in memory usage. But not the commend used by the OP (`graph.adjacency(B, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)`).

Comment: Not willing to try again. Love my machine too much :)

Comment: @Pascal, matrix B is random matrix with positive, non-integer numbers.

Comment: No problem with `B <- matrix(runif(3025*3025, 0, 10), nc = 3025)`.

Comment: @Pascal, thanks. It's problem with my PC. B <- matrix(runif(3025*3025, 0, 10), nc = 3025)
> g <- graph.adjacency(B, weighted=TRUE, mode="undirected", diag=FALSE)
Error in .Call("R_igraph_weighted_adjacency", adjmatrix, as.numeric(mode),  : 
  At type_indexededgelist.c:309 : cannot add edges, Out of memory
> object.size(g)
3152164 bytes
> object.size(B)
73205112 bytes'

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @GaborCsardi, thank you for attention on my question. I have updated my question with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The error never came from `library(igraph)`, it always came from `graph.adjacency`.
2. igraph is optimized for sparse graphs, your graph is a full graph, so this is not ideal.
3. Most importantly, you'll need more memory. This graph requires about 300 MB memory and apparently you don't have that.

I am not sure how you could call `object.size` on `g` if you failed to create it.

Comment: thanks for full answer. I think the result `object.size(g)` was obtained for an another (more smaller) igraph object and I should clear an igraph object like `B<-c()`.